# Showing information when hovering over Function/Class

Tags: java, function, deprecated

I am developing an API and I need to give some information to the user.

In my specific case, I am marking a Class as deprecated in my next release (I want it to be available but let the user know it will be removed in the near future).

I want to tell the user this function is deprecated when he/she hovers over it, an example (This shows information about how to use the function, mine is a bit different, I just want to show a little message with information):

[image: Example with DateFormat.format(Date date)]

**MY CASE**

I want to show the message `As of release 0.4.0, replaced by WhateverClass` when hovering over the class.

I have tried this in my project: (It obviously did not work, I wouldn't be here if it did)

```
/**
 * @deprecated  As of release 0.4.0, replaced by {@see main.chart.FXPieChart}
 */
@Deprecated
public class PieChart extends JPanel {
    //Whatever....
}
```

How can I achieve it?

(I hope I explained everything well, my English is far from perfect, please, feel free to edit if you see any spelling/grammar mistakes).

Thank you all.

**Update:**

This is what I see in my class:

[image: Hovering over PieChart (My Class)]

Comment: that shopuld work as it is supported by javadoc.... are you generating jars for that api? is the javadoc included there????

Comment: Please post the screenshot showing what do you see in your case

Comment: I just updated what I see in my case @Ivan

Comment: Which IDE are you using? NetBeans shows calls to deprecated methods by striking them out.

Comment: Eclipse Neon (4.6.0) on Windows 10.

Comment: Try updating to Eclipse Neon 4.6.1, it's possible this is a bug that's been fixed. https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse/releases/4.6.0/bugs lists more than 50 bugs regarding Javadoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a lot simpler than I thought and all my fault, not a bug.

**Solution:**

When compiling the .jar file and select the created JavaDoc, make sure you select the `Export all output folders for checked projects` option. Eclipse won't add the documentation files if you don't specifically tell it to.